# SQLite/Python 3 database - multiple records for each key

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite

```
AB_123, a location, unique_url, some_date, a name
AB_123, a location, unique_url, some_date, a name
AB_123, a location, unique_url, some_date, a name
AB_123, a location, unique_url, some_date, a name
CD_456, a location, unique_url, some_date, a name
EF_678, a location, unique_url, some_date, a name
EF_678, a location, unique_url, some_date, a name
EF_678, a location, unique_url, some_date, a name
GH_890, a location, unique_url, some_date, a name
GH_890, a location, unique_url, some_date, a name
```

My first database project so forgive my naive question.

My data is structured like this - a key (multiple instances) that will be used by consumers of my code to search on (e.g. AB_123), and return the data for all the rows that match. So SEARCH('AB_123) would return 4 rows of data in this example.

All fields are strings. Using Python 3 and SQLite. Around 320,000 records. Performance is less important that clarity.

My research suggests that multiple tables tables is the way to go but I quickly got lost. I've gotten close to a solution with a single table but I had to keep backtracking.

I feel like there is a simple, elegant solution out there, especially where performance is secondary.

Any pointers to what model I should look at?

-Molly

Comment: You should research database normalisation and, specifically, the 3rd normal form (3NF)

Comment: There's not really enough to go on here. As it stands ... you can accomplish your stated goal quite well. You could do exactly as you explained: search on AB_123 and return the four rows! But depending on what "a location" is, or what "a url" is, or even what "a name" is ... you might have various solutions. Generally speaking, advice on database design doesn't work very well in SO questions ... often they are closed.

Comment: @topsail - understood - i did mention they're all strings. Do you mean select records where ID (say) is "AB_123" and use what comes back?  I need a primary key don't I ?

Answer (score 0):

A "primary key" is unique. The ABC* column in the example is not unique, so it cannot be the "key".  It sounds like you want to [create an index](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html) on the first column, which will affect (usually in a positive way) the performance of the lookup.  If `unique_url` is indeed unique, that could be the primary key, but that is immaterial as regards searching the first column.

Comment: I see.  The requirement is that users can find records by the first field. `SELECT * WHERE ID=‘ABC_12’` Would that work with no primary key - just an index?

Comment: To answer your question, it will work without a primary key. For a large-ish table, indexing on this "key" is a good idea as noted in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could normalize this table into multiple tables like you suggested, or you could keep it flat and add a composite key. Good database design usually normalizes to at least 3rd form, although I was was taught to use [Bryce-Codd Normal Form (BCNF)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/boyce-codd-normal-form-bcnf/) as the standard, which is closer to 3.5 form.

You have a few options for the primary key. The best option in my opinion is to create a composite key using the column that you have labeled  and one of the other unique columns such as . There's a straight forward tutorial on primary keys and composite keys in SQLite [HERE](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-primary-key/).

Another option you could do is to use AUTOINCREMENT to create a unique primary key for each row as it is getting inserted into the database. Even though it sounds good, autoincrement isn't usually a great solution for production environments, you can read more about that [HERE](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).